# Don't display menu in release mode

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo

I want that the menu i have created for testing entries should come in debug mode but when i release(launch) my application the menu should not be displayed for testing entries. Can anyone help me for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `IS_DEBUG_MODE` flag in your application and add code in that..

Use `PackageManager` to get an `ApplicationInfo` object on your application, and check the flags field for `FLAG_DEBUGGABLE`.

```
boolean isDebuggable = (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE));
```

**Update:**

The following solution assumes that in manifest file you always set `android:debuggable=true` while developing and `android:debuggable=false` for application release.

Now you can check this attribute's value from your code by checking the `ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE` flag in the `ApplicationInfo` obtained from `PackageManager`.

The following code snippet could help:

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
int flags = packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags; 
if ((flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE) != 0) {
    // development mode
} else {
    // release mode
}
```

So in your manifest file:

For debug time,

```
<application android:name=".MyActivity" android:icon="@drawable/myicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
```

For release time,

```
<application android:name=".MyActivity" android:icon="@drawable/myicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false">
```